# If an establishment allows breastfeeding, but not outside drinks (juice, etc.), is bottled breastmilk an exception?

Tags: breastfeeding, bottle-feeding

I'm visiting an indoor kids park (trampolines, slides, etc.) with a "no outside drink" policy.

I understand the reason for the policy is to up sell, and while my toddler son *can* drink their (cow) milk for $.50/oz, I'd rather save money and just bring my own.

My understanding is that they can't prevent me from breastfeeding. I'm trying to use that idea to allow my son to have a bottle. Is bottled breast milk seen as the same?

Comment: It seems like the park is more prepared to answer a question about their policies than an unaffiliated web site is. Have you tried contacting them to ask? This question seems to be more about some location's private policies rather than parenting technique.

Comment: I'd have to agree with @JasonC.  Hope you can get this answered by them, with a positive reply.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it really is about dealing with a business' policies for bringing in outside drinks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've never seen an establishment prevent parents from giving bottled (as in baby bottle) milk to their kids, whether that is breast milk or formula.

Very few places (none?) will be prepared to correctly prepare a baby bottle to force you to buy it directly from them.  Think of all the issues involved in that.

I would be extremely surprised if they gave you any grief when you pulled out the baby bottle.  If it was me, I'd not even ask them.  Just do what you need to for your kids.

Answer (score 7):

In general, while I would be surprised if they did not let you in, the best way to find out is to ask them. Contacting the establishment in question is the appropriate and most accurate way to clarify policies that you are unsure about.

So, you could probably just go with the bottle, but to be sure find some contact info (perhaps they have a web site or a phone number) and ask before you go. Even if it is completely unreasonable, you still don't want to get turned away at the door. It's always best to be clear about the rules of an establishment you are visiting before you visit and the best way to get that clarity is to ask the establishment.

Any answers anybody here would give you would be purely conjecture, albeit based on some educated and likely correct guesses.

Comment: This is a great answer to a less-than-great question. Well done!

Answer (score 2):

In general, in my experience, businesses do not approach you for bringing in food or drinks for infants.

This has included bottle breast milk, juice, water, crackers, treats, fruit snacks, meal/snack squeeze pouches, and much more.

**My rule of thumb is that if my child is not old enough to be charged admission, then the rules prohibiting outside food and drink don't apply.** However, even for my toddler we still make sure to carry certain snacks on hand in the diaper bag to ensure his dietary requirements are met. We can't guarantee vendors will have the proper food, or that we'll be able to get it soon enough to sate him. For instance, when we visited the zoo, it could be a long walk between water fountains.

You can check with the business beforehand, but **I'd rather ask forgiveness than permission in this case**. I find it very unlikely that most employees will approach you for feeding your young child, even if their business policy says otherwise. I think reasonable people will recognize that it's not something worth confronting a customer about. So, I would not plan around the exception.

Answer (score 0):

That rule is meant to encourage purchase of food and drink from on-site vendors.  Since the baby is not ever going to buy food and drink on-site, the probably won't care.

Comment: What's obvious to you may not be to others. Remember to be respectful. This is okay, but its tone does hint "stop being stupid".